# How to bring up message if email closed without sending?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I know this is very basic, but having a total mind blank right now.
I have my basic code to send an email in outlook, but I need to know the line to bring up an error or message if the person closes the email without sending.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Sends email

With OutMail
    .to = " someone@nowhere.com"
    .Subject = " Rich Request"
    .HTMLBody = "Please find attached new     request"    .Attachments.AddApplication.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  .Display

End With

Set OutApp = Nothing
```